# The proof using intermediate value theorem

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

> Prove the following ‘fixed point theorem’: For every continuous
> function $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ there exists $x ∈ [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = x$

Proof:
Let function $g(x)=f(x)-x$，and because $f(x)$ and $x$ are continuous on [0,1], $g(x)$ is also continuous on [0,1]

Then because the codomain of $f(x)$ is [0,1],   $0\leq f(x)\leq1 \implies -x\leq f(x)-x\leq 1-x$

Thus,$-x\leq g(x)\leq 1-x$ and in particular $0\leq g(0)\leq 1$ and $-1\leq g(1)\leq 0$

Hence, $g(1)\leq 0\leq g(0)$ and then there exists a $x\in[0,1]$ such that $g(x)=0$

As a result, there exists a $x\in[0,1]$ such that  $f(x)=x$

Is this a correct proof? The thing I'm not sure about is that the intermediate value theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on [a,b] and with $f(a)<c<f(b)$. Then there exists a $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=c$. However, in this proof, I use "less or equal to" rather than strictly "less that" . Will this make something wrong?

Comment: weak inequality works as well. Suppose for example in the intermediate value theorem that $f(a)=c$. Then, there's actually nothing to prove because you have already found a point in the interval $[a,b]$ (namely $a$) which gets mapped by the function $f$ to $c$. Similarly, if $f(b)=c$, then again, there's nothing to prove. So, the difficult/interesting part of the theorem is when we have strict inequality, but the version with weak inequalities is still correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct and the fact that it only assumes that $g(1)\leqslant0\leqslant g(0)$ instead of the stronger $g(1)<0<g(0)$ is not a problem. That's so because if $g(1)=0$, you can take $x=1$, and if $g(0)=0$, you can take $x=0$. Otherwise, you'll have $g(1)<0<g(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is basically correct. To account for the $</\leq$ difference, you just need to add a line stating something along the lines of the following:

If $g(0)=0$ or $g(1)=0$, then we clearly have a value where $f(x)=x$. Otherwise we have $g(0)<0<g(1)$.

From there you can use the IVT as you described.